# Can't install xposed framework

Tags: xposed-framework

I want to install the xposed framework on my Nexus 5 and in the framework, the install/update option doesn't work.

My Nexus 5 runs Android 5.0 (Lollipop).

Comment: Are you running Android 5.0 (Lollipop)? The xposed framework doesn't support it yet...

Answer (score 3):

The xposed framework does not [currently support](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52288979&postcount=3) Android 5 (Lollipop). More specifically it doesn't work on the ART runtime which is available as a developer option on 4.4 and the only available runtime in Lollipop. You will have to wait for the xposed framework to be updated in order to install it on your Nexus 5 (or downgrade to 4.4 if it's that important).

Ryan's comment appears to show that it's actually the API level but I believe that's a side effect / symptom of running the ART runtime.

Comment: ART isn't the problem with xposed any more. I had xposed running with my LG G3, while running in ART. xposed doesn't yet support SDK version 21, or armeabi-v7a. http://i.imgur.com/2rzvG5g.png

Comment: @bmdixon Time to edit this answer.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Alpha version of Xposed is now available for Lollipop on ARMv7 and higher devices, so you should be able to install it without issue on the Nexus 5.  Refer to the XDA thread for all the details:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/official-xposed-lollipop-t3030118

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Link only answers are not good answers. You could include information like how it is alpha release. How it currently only works on ARMv7 devices. The link itself does not explain how it helps answer the question.